# Kubespray scale Ansible playbook cannot find /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

I want to extend my Kubernetes cluster by one node.

So I run the scale.yaml Ansible playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/local/hosts.ini  --become --become-user=root scale.yml
```

But I am getting the error message when uploading the control plane certificates happens:

```
TASK [Upload control plane certificates] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [jay]
fatal: [sam]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/kubeadm", "init", "phase", "--config", "/etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml", "upload-certs", "--upload-certs"], "delta": "0:00:00.039489", "end": "2022-01-08 11:31:37.708540", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-01-08 11:31:37.669051", "stderr": "error execution phase upload-certs: failed to load admin kubeconfig: open /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf: no such file or directory\nTo see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher", "stderr_lines": ["error execution phase upload-certs: failed to load admin kubeconfig: open /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf: no such file or directory", "To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the error you have the line `To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher"`. Please run the command with `--v=5` or better `--v=9` and paste the result to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself.

I copied the /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf and /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.* to the new node and now the scale playbook works. Maybe this is not the right way, but it worked...